# Javafx Gridpane Cell Background Colors

Tags: java, css, text, javafx

So I have a javafx program which procedurally creates text nodes and inserts them into a GridPane. Each of these text nodes is given a CSS class. I used a stylesheet, to try to make the cells of each class a different color. However, I can only use the `-fx-fill` property to change the text color, which is good, but I cannot find anything online as to how to change the background of each cell through CSS or Java. I have also tried the `fx-background-color` property in the CSS, but that doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated; thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a `Region`, or some subclass of `Region`, in order to set the background color.

Either:

Use a `Label` instead of a `Text`. You can set the text color with `-fx-text-fill` and the background color with `-fx-background-color`.

Or:

Create a `StackPane` for each `Text`; add the `Text` to the `StackPane` and the `StackPane` to the `GridPane`. You can set the text color with `-fx-fill` on the `Text` and the background color with `-fx-background-color` on the `StackPane`. You will probably need to call

```
GridPane.setFillHeight(myStackPane, true);
GridPane.setFillWidth(myStackPane, true);
```

on each `StackPane` to get the `StackPane` to fill the `GridPane` cell.

Answer (score 0):

You can use stackpane as well change background color of stackpane. Add the node of single cell in stackpane and after you need to add stackpane in grid

```
grid.getChildren.add(pane,0,1);
```